# OWA (Outlook Web Access) won't give user a link to attached document. Gives "Open as Web Page"

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-web-app, pdf

I have been testing OWA and have found that when there is an attached file on a message it shows the "Attachments:" then the file name (but no link) and then [Open as Web Page] link. The user has to click on that which opens a new window and previews the document, then the user gets "You are currently viewing:" followed by the file name. This time the file name is a link that they can open/download. This happens for Office documents and PDF file at least.

How do I make it so users can get a direct link to the file on the original message window?

Here is a picture of what the user sees when they select a message from the inbox.

[image: Not what I want... :(]

Here is what my entire screen looks like. 
[image]

Comment: Is this a windows 2000 server?

Comment: What version of Exchange/OWA are you using?  How are users accessing the OWA (what browser, etc)

Comment: I am not sure. I'm not the admin, I'm just trying to find out what's wrong so I can tell them what exactly to do to fix it. Since without that they will brush it off and do nothing. Any way to tell which version just from the OWA portal? IE 7 is the browser users are using.

Comment: Just found the about and its says "Microsoft Office Outlook Web Access for Microsoft Exchange Server 2007"

Comment: Weird figured an older version would give you this issue. I am on 2003 and it works.
The admins may have changed the way users can view/download attachments in OWA may wanna check with them.

Comment: +1 @Campo this would be my guess.  Probably something in the MIME type.

Comment: "I am not sure. I'm not the admin". Then better talk to the admin, who is the one who should be asking questions on this site, not the end user.

Comment: Well generally everyone at this company doesn't have a clue about their IT job, so if I don't know exactly what to tell them to do to make a change they won't be able to do it.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? @Jerry did you ask the admins if they changed the way attachments are handled in OWA?

Comment: Yes I was finally able to get the admins to check and it was because some one had set it this way. The fun part is they don't know who or why so I'm still trying to get them to change it.

Comment: Just a follow up Gald you got it working I am going to answer the question if you wouldn't mind marking it right. I feel I was the first to suggest that someone changed the setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admins must have changed the setting.

In a comment I asked Jerry to check. He asked his admins and they confirmed and fixed the problem.

Comment: This answer is practically useless to those who are trying to solve this problem.  What setting?  Where is it located?  How do I get to it?  It was a waste of my time to even click on this thread through Google.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the attachment
Click "Save link as"

Done!

Just tested this with a .docx

EDIT:
Screenshot
[alt text http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/example.JPG](http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/example.JPG)

If that is to hard to see [click here](http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/example.JPG)

Comment: That's what I want to do but its not an option when you are viewing the email. There is NO link to the attachment, only a link to "Open as Web Page" and from that pop up window you then get the link to the file that you can right click and "Save link as".

Comment: This is for .doc etc....

Emails that have an email as an attachment exhibit the characteristics you describe in your comment. I edited my post to include a screen grab of what I see.

Comment: I just posted a complete screen shot of my OWA site, and it looks quite different from yours. I've tried right clicking and save as but its not treating the file name as a link (like yours does). It doesn't even pop up a context menu when I right click.

Comment: Admins may have disabled the feature see my comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

This was an setting set by some admin.

Why: They don't know, and until they do they won't change it back...

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.